# Give 2d image customization to produce real view

Tags: html5-canvas

Is it possible to add image/text on the 2d image so that it gives a real view.For example as present in : http://www.zazzle.com/make_your_own_iphone_5_case-179092402149274498.

Comment: Sure. You can use html5 canvas compositing to apply image/text to the phone case. If your user's browsers support the new canvas blend compositing your results will be even better. Start with this link and come back with a new question if you have specific coding issues: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation.

Comment: But I basically want to add image/text in such a way that when they are moved left/right/top/bottom the added image/text gets adjusted according to the shape of the mobile case as present in above link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These views are orthographic and isometric views and they can be reproduced using affine transformations in canvas, as they are also parallelograms.

First you will need to make masks for the different cases. These needs to be drawn in the same orientation as the case in the "photo". Use solid pixels (any color will do, it won't show in later step) where you want the custom graphics to show, transparent pixels anywhere else (anti-aliased pixels are fine).

Then draw in the mask in the canvas, select composite mode "source-in" to replace non-transparent pixels and finally, select blending mode "multiply" and draw the case "photo" on top to mix in shadows and highlights. The latter step is what will give the illusion of the image having depth.

For the isometric views, calculate the skew angle (or use trial and error if you're not sure if the image is accurate - this is as a rule-of-thumb usually tan(60°), ie. `transform(1, 0, Math.tan(60/180*Math.PI), 1, 0, 0)`), then do the same process as above. Just remember only apply transformation when drawing the custom image, mask and top layer must be drawn without transformations.

The orthographic side views can be generated using scaling for the x-axis. Depending on which angle, add a stripe for the side of the case.

### Example of steps

```js
var img = new Image(),
    cust = new Image(),
    count = 2,
    ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
img.onload = cust.onload = comp;
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/je0Jh.png";
cust.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRPDt.png";

function comp() {
  if (--count) return;
  
  // draw in mask
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  
  // comp. mode source-in
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
  
  // draw in custom graphics
  ctx.drawImage(cust, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    // blend mode multiply
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";

  // draw in original case multiplied (does not work in IE)
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<canvas with=263 height=505></canvas>
```

The quality largely depends on the quality of the mask - I made a very quick-n-dirty version here as you can see (your case image can also act as the mask btw).

The steps are the same for the isometric view with the exception of the skew transform. Multiply does not work in IE, you can use alpha here instead or make a separate mask containing only shadows etc.

That being said: remember that this is not the image sent to production. This will just show a representation of the final result. What is used is the image, image position and size. These data is then used to build an unmasked flat print-template which is used to make the phone-case.

Comment: Hello K3N, Thanks for such a great explanation :-).It was very helpful for me. But I want to clear some doubts: 1.) When I use some tilted image as in bottom image preview of mobile case,the image that user uploads(here in your case the 'cust' image source) is displayed straight in the canvas not on the tilted mobile case.So for that what should I do?   2.) Secondly,the use of transform is not clear to me. Please put some more light on the same.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello K3N & MarkE, I know I am coming with too many questions. But I am grateful atleast you have helped me initiate in the right direction. I have made a good headway now but need a last bit of push to reach to conclusion. Hope you can help me once more in completing this critical project. Basically, I am facing problem with the customizable part i.e. making the superimposed image/text over the phone case as draggable & resizable as can be done in the link (http://www.zazzle.com/make_your_own_iphone_5_case-179092402149274498). I cant thank you enough for helping me with this.